# python3 subprocess module can not work for cp

Tags: linux, shell, subprocess, python-3.6, cp

the code as following, but i cat find why the error occured, when I run "cp -rf  /tmp/test.py 
 /tmp/blacktest/" it works fine

```
>>> subprocess.call(['cp','-rf','/tmp/test\.py','/tmp/blacktest/'],shell=True)
 cp: missing file operand
 Try 'cp --help' for more information.
 1
```

Comment: I also tried the  subprocess.call(['cp','-rf','/tmp/test.py','/tmp/blacktest/'],shell=True), but got the same error

Comment: `shell=True` Tip: When you run `sh -c cp -rf /tmp/test.py /tmp/balcktest` you will get the same error. Do you understand what `shell` does?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:
remove shell=True (also remove backslash before '.', why do you need it?) like:

```
subprocess.call(['cp','-rf','/tmp/test.py','/tmp/blacktest/']
```

**Advice**: Use python facility to copy file

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

**Long answer**:

shell=True would prepend you command with /bin/sh -c

This means that FIRST argument coming after -c is a command to execute using /bin/sh. This first argument of yours is `cp` which is then executed alone, *without any arguments*... That is why you see the error message.

You could still run using shell=true if you tell it ALL your arguments is actually one single command for the shell:

```
subprocess.call(['cp -rf q.py w'], shell=True)
```